# Security of database connection parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php 
class Database {

    private $host       = "localhost";
    private $username   = "root";
    private $password   = "";
    private $dbname     = "myapp"; 

    public $conn;

    public function DBConnection() {
        $this->conn = null;
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);

            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MOD, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch(PDOException $exception) {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;

    }
}             
?>
```

I am using the above PDO method to connect to my database.  However, if I try to create a new instance of this class on a different page say debug.php like:

```
$db = new Database();
```

It throws all the parameters including my password in the page source.

My question is what are the chances of my database security being compromised as a result of this?

Comment: _"It throws all the parameters including my password in the page source."_ I don't understand this, can you explain? Do you mean the credentials show up in the stack trace?

Comment: PHP is executed server-side. Any parameters, data, functions.... will not be visible in the browser unless you tell it to - by using some sort of print method. That being said, any config files you have should be stored outside of the public folder

Answer (score 1):

You should never store authentication credentials (userids, passwords, API keys) in your source code, especially if you use a source control system like git. As soon as you `git push` then anybody with read access to the repository gets write access to the database. There are a few common alternatives:

1. Store the credentials in environment variables that are explicitly set within the web server's configuration.
2. Store the credentials in a config file (like a YAML or INI file) that is outside the web server's document root directory, and then read that file in your application's bootstrap. (And don't include that file in the source control repository!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and help!